# Embed taglib within anchor tag in jsp to call different servlets

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

Header

```
      <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

//  Options in the menu bar-

```
      <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal"<c:set var="role" value="admin" scope="session" />>Log in as Administrator</a> 
      <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal"<c:set var="role" value="user" scope="session" />>Log in as User</a>
```

//select a servlet depending on the set value

```
  <c:choose>
  <c:when test="{role == 'admin'}">
  <div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" onclick="window.location.href='AdminServlet.java'">Login</button>
</div>
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
<div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" onclick="window.location.href='UserServlet.java'">Login</button>
</div>
 </c:otherwise>
                        </c:choose>
```

Please suggest how I can use taglib tags as above to call the servlets depending on the set values.Above code is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code `<c:set var="role" value="admin" scope="session" />` is just setting variable, not printing it in actual html, to print it you must use either `c:out` or just `${role}` after setting it

Also you've forgot `$` in `<c:when test="{role == 'admin'}">`, so it should be `<c:when test="${role == 'admin'}">`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are trying to load an iframe in a model where a login option is displayed. The model will be loaded on clicking one of the anchor elements (one for admin and other for normal user )

Setting the c:set from inside the anchor wont work as anchor is client side component and c:set is evaluated in server itself .

Instead, use a new jsp as the href of the anchor  and pass the user role selection as a parameter as follows

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal" href="/loginPage.jsp?role=admin">Log in as Administrator</a> 
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal" href="/loginPage.jsp?role=user"  >Log in as User</a>
```

Now in your loginpage.jsp define the button as follows -

```
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${role == 'admin'}"> 
    <c:set var="action" value ="/adminLogin" />
<c:otherwise>

 </c:otherwise>
    <c:set var="action" value ="/userLogin" />
 </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
 <form action="${ action}">
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
 </form>
```

Note : You need to provide url mapping in the web.xml for /userLogin and /adminLogin to map to respective servlets